# nodejs / javascript variable overwritten

Tags: javascript, node.js

When my server receives a request, I create a dispatcher which creates a router and ask to my router the controller that my dispatcher needs, so I send a URL to my router and with an array with every path. My router sends the controller to my dispatcher and my dispatcher calls the controlle `index() func...`

So my problem is, when I initialize my controllers, my controllers are overwritten by the last controller. Could someone tell me why?

This is my router, I've created a small code with logs to show the problem:

```
function Router(){
    log(colors.green+"Router initialization...")
    this.indexController = new (require("../controllers/index"))();
    log(this.indexController.constructor.name);

    this.notFoundController = new (require("../controllers/notFound"))();
    log(this.notFoundController.constructor.name);

    this.publicController = new (require("../controllers/public"))();
    log(this.publicController.constructor.name);

    this.faviconController = new (require("../controllers/favicon"))();
    log(this.faviconController.constructor.name);

    this.registerController = new (require("../controllers/register"))();
    log(this.registerController.constructor.name);
    log(colors.green+"Router initialization successful")

    log(this.indexController.constructor.name);
    log(this.notFoundController.constructor.name);
    log(this.publicController.constructor.name);
    log(this.faviconController.constructor.name);
    log(this.registerController.constructor.name);
}
```

console logs :

```
Log(21:9:4): Router initialization...
Log(21:9:4): IndexController
Log(21:9:4): NotFoundController
Log(21:9:4): PublicController
Log(21:9:4): FaviconController
Log(21:9:4): RegisterController
Log(21:9:4): Router initialization successful
Log(21:9:4): RegisterController
Log(21:9:4): RegisterController
Log(21:9:4): RegisterController
Log(21:9:4): RegisterController
Log(21:9:4): RegisterController
```

Why are my variables overwritten?

register.js:

```
function RegisterController() {}
RegisterController.prototype = Controller.prototype;
RegisterController.prototype.constructor = RegisterController;
RegisterController.prototype.index = function(content) {
    if (content.req.method == "POST") {
        content.res.writeHeader(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        content.res.write(content.datas);
        content.res.end();
    } else {
        this.render.call(content, "register");
    }
}
module.exports = RegisterController;
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `controllers/register.js`, please?

Comment: function RegisterController(){
}

RegisterController.prototype = Controller.prototype;
RegisterController.prototype.constructor = RegisterController;

RegisterController.prototype.index = function(content){
 if(content.req.method == "POST"){
  content.res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"}); 
  content.res.write(content.datas);
  content.res.end();
 }
 else{
  this.render.call(content, "register");
 }
}

module.exports = RegisterController;

Comment: No, no, please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments. Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `Controller.prototype` to `RegisterController.protoype` and then *modifying* it:

```
RegisterController.prototype = Controller.prototype;
RegisterController.prototype.constructor = RegisterController;
```

This will modify the prototype of every controller in your program.

I'm assuming that the `.js` files for all of your controllers are doing this, and the first half of your output just *looks* right because you're logging them one at a time. That would explain the output at the end, because they're all sharing the same `constructor`.

You need to make a copy of the prototype before you modify it:

```
RegisterController.prototype = Object.create(Controller.prototype);
```

---

As a side note, contrary to what you thought, the variables in the code you showed us were not being overwritten. If you had done this:

```
console.log(this.indexController === this.notFoundController);
```

You would have seen:

```
false
```